# Orthogonality of states in the reciprocal space

Tags: quantum-mechanics, condensed-matter, hilbert-space, solid-state-physics, fourier-transform

I'm working on a Tight-Binding model problem, in particular, I want to prove that a particular set of eigenstates are orthogonal: $$|{\vec{k}}\rangle=\frac{1}{\sqrt{N^d}}\sum_n e^{i(\vec{k}-\vec{k}')\cdot\vec{r_n}}$$
Hence, I have:
$${\langle\vec{k}}|{\vec{k}'}\rangle=\frac{1}{N^d}\sum_n e^{i(\vec{k}-\vec{k}')\cdot\vec{r_n}}$$
This should be equal to $\delta_{\vec{k},\vec{k}'}$. It is trivial to show it is $1$ for $\vec{k}=\vec{k}'$, but how do I prove that it is $0$ for  $\vec{k}\neq\vec{k}'$?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In one dimension,
$$\frac{1}{N} \sum_{x=0}^{N-1} e^{i(k-k')x} = \frac{1}{N} \sum_{x=0}^{N-1} [e^{i(k-k')}]^x,$$
a geometric series.  This is just
$$\dfrac{1-e^{i(k-k')N}}{1-e^{i(k-k')}} = 0$$
as the reciprocal lattice is quantized to be integer multiples of $2\pi/N$ when we're using periodic boundary conditions.  The numerator is zero.

The three dimensional case is treated by splitting the exponentials into each of the Cartesian components.

Comment: Thank you very much! Completely forgot about geometric series!